# How to remove date and time in logfile in java

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging, logfile

I'm trying to create a log file in java, but the problem is, Whenever any thing is writing inside the log file(.txt file) it is showing the date and time . I want this to be removed every time when I'm writing anything inside the logfile.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class Logfile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");  
        FileHandler fh;  

        try {  


            fh = new FileHandler("D:\\New/MyLogFile.log");  
            logger.addHandler(fh);
            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
            fh.setFormatter(formatter);  


            logger.info("My first log");  

        } catch (SecurityException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  

        logger.info("Hi How r u?");  



    }

    }
```

Aug 21, 2019 4:33:51 PM Log.Logfile main
INFO: My first log
Aug 21, 2019 4:33:51 PM Log.Logfile main
INFO: Hi How r u?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a custom Formatter which provides a format function

```java
public class MyCustomFormatter extends Formatter {
    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord message) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(record.getLevel());
        sb.append(": ");
        sb.append(record.getMessage());
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

And assign you custom formatter

```java
fh.setFormatter(new MyCustomFormatter());
```

Provided log

> logger.info("My first log");

will result in

> INFO: My first log

Please read [LogRecord documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html) to log more informations